# How to integrate ace editor in angular for different languages?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9, ace-editor

I want to integrate an online compiler in my project. My project's frontend base is Angular.
So after many look in google I found the Ace Editor. The editor looks great and is easy to implement but I want to know is there any way of using other language except **javascript**. I have found this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ace-code-editor-hrp6zr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example but here if I set other language except javascript in this line:

```
this.editor.mode = 'java';
```

the editor is throwing error.

> ERROR Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>
> Unable to display error. Open your browser's console to view.

Is their any way to solve this ?
Or if anyone can suggest any way of creating a compiler or free compiler that I can integrate in my project.

Comment: Ace editor is NOT a compiler. Its just a editor (text area where you can get/display code with formatting and syntax highlighting).

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r but in the example I am seeing it can evaluate also

Comment: Can you share the example link

Comment: please see the question the link is there. The word "Stackblitz" is the link

Comment: In that example they are using `eval()` function of javascript which evaluates an string as if it was native code. So you can write `alert('hi')` in that editor and can see the popup. But ace editor is not compiling anything. More info on `eval` : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: can you suggest me any compiler api that I can integrate in my project ?

Comment: Sorry i haven't worked with any compiler available for web project and i dont think it exists as free and open-source.

Comment: try importing either `ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-java` or `brace/mode/java`

Comment: will it evaluate the results ?

Comment: an EDITOR can highlight a language by a syntax, but not compile it. You need to write your own compiler and pass the text to it